# Eclipse, aptana - FTP authentication failed

Tags: eclipse, ftp, aptana

I'm trying to use the aptana plugin over eclipse for FTP connection to a server. 
I followed the instructions from [here](http://www.karlsteltenpohl.com/blog/,61,) and it all went well. However when I come to actually establish the connection, I keep getting:
an error message saying: "Authentication failed".

I used a username and password I'm using all the time with other applications without any problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure you are using the right connection type: FTP, SFTP, FTPS?

Comment: I'm using FTP. What do you mean by the "right connection"? which of them isn't right?

Comment: It depends on your server configuration - it may not allow connections over FTP, only over SFTP, e.g. If you have another program that is working with these credentials, you should check what port it is using and if there is anything about the connection type.

Comment: Yeah, SFTP worked, thanks. You can put it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using the correct connection type. If you have other programs that are working with these credentials, verify they are connecting using the same protocol (SFTP, FTP, FTPS). Many servers will not allow connections over plain FTP, my first guess if FTP is not working would be to try SFTP.